# Does asp.net auto generate Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

If I create a new VS project and copy the following example code into a new page `default.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
                <div id="top-menu" class="float-right">
                <ul class="main">
                    <li><a id="A1" href="#"  runat="server" class="current"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Members</span></a>
                        <ul class="sub curved">
                            <li><a href="#">MemberPage1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MemberPage2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MemberPage3</a></li>                           
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Admin</span></a>  </li>
                    <li><a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick ="Scan_Click"><span>Scan</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run I get the following in my browser when I hover over Scan - `Javascript:_doPostBack('ctl02','')`

[image]

Being very new to ASP.NET this has surprised me as I didn't know I was using javascript so I hope this isn't a silly question......

If a user disables javascript in their browser (eg as advised by Tor recently) does it mean the server side event Scan_Click won't run?

If so is there an alternative to run server side scripts on an asp.net site with javascript disabled in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET uses JavaScript for the Postback feature, so it won't run without JavaScript enabled.

If you want to run your application without JavaScript you must move to ASP.NET MVC and use regular POST actions.

But beware that in this other approach you won't have all those fancy controls like Calendar, Menu or even Button, everything is plain HTML.

Comment: that's not completely true. You can use a classic form post to post the data to the page without using JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, you're right but in the question's sample @ooo is using the Menu control, that won't run at all without js enabled ;-)

Comment: All those fancy controls are all html, that is what the user is served. Although a calendar control wouldnt be effective without javascript

Answer (score 1):

> If a user disables javascript in their browser (eg as advised by Tor recently) does it mean the server side event Scan_Click won't run?

Yep, the `runat="server"` attribute allows ASP.NET to translates your `onserverclick` event into some client-side code it can invoke via JS - if JS is disabled this code can't be triggered.

> If so is there an alternative to run server side scripts on an asp.net site with javascript disabled in the browser?

You could manually write the HTML output which gives you control over *how* you invoke the postback, that way you can make sure you don't rely on JS. However, you need to weigh up the likelihood of your site functioning in general without JS enabled let alone just for postbacks.

Comment: Hyperlinks aren't the only place ASP.Net uses postback, are they? I thought it was used rather more extensively than that -- select box changes, buttons...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nah your correct, it can be used in the case of input fields etc. I have updated my answer to be more general.